# How to find the rolling 3 months variance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a dataset with two columns, date, and amount. I would like to find the past 3 month variance (VAR), then aggregate the variance (VAR) by averaging them (AVG) by month. I also want to make sure that if less than 3 month data is available, then not to calculate the variance. (so I have 6 months of data, I will only have the an average variance for the last 3 months). Many thanks

note: I am using SSMS

```
Date                 Amount
23 February 2017    £41,079
07 January 2017     £25,856
....
```

Comment: Is it even useful to have a variance over 3 values?

Comment: You are right! I think it is better to take the daily variance (past 90 days), then average them by month ?

Comment: I edited the question accordingly, thanks @Onno

Comment: Please define "variance" as you are using it in this statement.

Comment: Variance as in VAR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in aggregation/window function [`var()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/var-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if your definition of variance matches what this function does.

If you have one day per row and are willing to accept 90 days as "3 months", then you can simply do:

```
select t.*, var(amount) over (order by date rows between 89 preceding and current row) as rolling_var
from t;
```

If these conditions are not true, a much less efficient method uses a self-join:

```
select t.date, t.amount, var(t2.amount)
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.date > dateadd(month, -3, t.date) and t2.date <= t.date
group by t.date, t.amount;
```

Comment: There is more than one record per day. I tried running your second suggestion based on self-join, but has been running for over 20 minutes. ( I have 400k records)